# TableViewのSectionHeader部分に線を表示したい

Tags: swift, swift2, uitableview

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

TableViewのSectionHeader部分に下線を表示したいと考えています。
現在は上の画像のようになっています。
設定画面と同じように線を表示することはできますか？

また各セクションの最後まで下線を引いて欲しいのですが、
表示されていません。こちらもどのようにすると表示できますでしょうか。

```
import UIKit

class TableViewTest: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    private let mySection: NSArray = ["Section1", "Section2"]
    private let myItem: NSArray = ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5"]
    private let myItem2: NSArray = ["Item6"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.myTable.respondsToSelector(Selector("separatorInset")) {
            self.myTable.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }

        if self.myTable.respondsToSelector(Selector("layoutMargins")) {
            self.myTable.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return mySection.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return mySection[section] as? String
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if section == 0 {
            return myItem.count
        } else if section == 1 {
            return myItem2.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let item = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("separatorInset")) {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        }

        if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins")) {
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false;
        }

        if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("layoutMargins")) {
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        }
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            item.text = myItem[indexPath.row] as? String
        } else if indexPath.section == 1{
            item.text = myItem2[indexPath.row] as? String
        }

        return cell

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) を参照すればわかりますが、`UITableView` は Content Cell だけでなく、Header Cell や Footer Cell もカスタマイズすることができます。

また、「設定」アプリのような外観を実現したいだけであれば、`style` プロパティに `.Grouped` を指定するだけでいいです。セクションの下線も引かれます。

この設定は StoryBoard からも行えます。

[image: styleの設定方法]

Comment: これです！ありがとうございます！